# What is the name of this method Class::function($params)?

Tags: php-7.2

I did some research but I just don't know what the term or word its called.

Here is an example:

```
Class Exam {

 public static function test($id)
 {
    return $id;
 }

}

echo Exam::test(1);
```

What I want to search is... I wan't to understand minified method of calling the class and function in one line. Just like laravel. I am by the way coding in native.

Comment: :: calls a static method. in this case, class Exam, static method test

Comment: Okay @KaiQing thanks! you should put that in answer

Comment: Added. I suggest reading php docs on static methods, variables, etc. That might be more insightful than my vague answer

Comment: @KaiQing Okay thank you for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a question that pops up on stack overflow often.

`Classname::method();` is just a shorter way of calling a static method in a class. When using `::` you do not need to instantiate the class first. Consider the following -

```
Class Classname{
    static public $var = date("F j, Y");

    static public method(){
        return self::$var;
    }
}

echo Classname::method();

$c = new Classname();
echo $c->method();
```

both echo lines will echo today's date in F j, Y format.

Why use a static method? Consider this example above where you have a date format and you want that to be an immutable value. A static method is stateless. So in the example we have a static method accessing a static variable. Static properties cannot access the class as an object like `$this` would. But you can access the class itself if you are accessing other static properties. `Classname::$var` or `self::$var` would be valid.

I know, I kind of didn't answer the "why" part you didn't ask about per say. It just dawned on me that my best answer is "I don't know." I know what a static method or property is, but I don't really have an iron clad example of where you would specifically use one AND in that same example explain why you MUST use a static method where a public one would be the difference between life and death. I welcome others with actual experience to post answers on when and why you would use a static method where the static part is axiomatically critical. I know that wasn't the OP's actual question, but really without knowing and truly understanding the purpose or necessity of static methods and properties, what's the point of factoring `::` into your daily code?

Comment: I have 3 reasons. 1.) `it looks cool.` 2.) `it looks elegant.` 3.) `it shortens the code.`. Also, Is it really risky? what are the risks?

Comment: And also I am trying to copy Laravels eloquent method. Its public and calls statically. I don't know how they did it yet.

Comment: but that's sort of my point. aside shaving bytes off your file sizes, I can't think of many reasons something has to be static. I'm a client based programmer though. What I make daily tends to fall in the same categories so I myself don't often have a reason to insist on static, but others may. And real reasons where the gains don't surpass the gain of not using php in the first place.

Comment: I will do more research now. Now that I know what its called. Thanks!